# "for" loop in R and checking previous value from a column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm working on a data frame which looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abw4v8h69e92yeq/idafootfall.csv?dl=0)

Here's how it looks like:

```
shape id day     hour week id footfall category          area name
22496   22/3/14  3    12      634      Work cluster     CBD area 1  
22670   22/3/14  3    12      220      Shopping cluster Orchard Road 1  
23287   22/3/14  3    12      723      Airport  Changi  Airport 2   
16430   22/3/14  4    12      947      Work cluster     CBD area 2  
4697    22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2    
4911    22/3/14  3    12      1001     Shopping cluster Orchard Rd 3    
11126   22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2
```

and so on... until 635 rows return.

and the other dataset that I want to compare with can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wf54t8xlpef2ds/footfall.csv?dl=0)

Here's how it looks like:

```
category         Foreigners Locals
Work cluster     1600000    3623900
Shopping cluster 1800000    3646666.667
Airport          15095152   8902705
Residential area 527700     280000
```

They both share the same attribute, i.e. `category`

I want to check if I can compare the **previous hour** from the column `hour` in the first dataset so I can compare it with the value from the second dataset.

Here's, what I ideally want to find in R:

```
#for n in 1: number of rows{
    # check the previous hour from IDA dataset !!!!
    # calculate hourSum - previousHour = newHourSum and store it as newHourSum
    # calculate hour/(newHourSum-previousHour) * Foreigners and store it as footfallHour
    # add to the empty dataframe }
```

I'm not sure how to do that and here's what i tried:

```
tbl1 <- secondDataset
tbl2 <- firstDataset
mergetbl <- function(tbl1, tbl2)
{

  newtbl = data.frame(hour=numeric(),forgHour=numeric(),locHour=numeric())

  ntbl1rows<-nrow(tbl1) # get the number of rows

  for(n in 1:ntbl1rows)
  {

    #get the previousHour
    newHourSum <- tbl1$hour - previousHour
    footfallHour <- (tbl1$hour/(newHourSum-previousHour)) * tbl2$Foreigners
    #add to newtbl   
  }
}
```

This would what i expected:

```
shape id day     hour week id footfall category          area name    forgHour  locHour 
22496   22/3/14  3    12      634      Work cluster     CBD area 1     1         12
22670   22/3/14  3    12      220      Shopping cluster Orchard Road 1 21        25
23287   22/3/14  3    12      723      Airport  Changi  Airport 2      31        34
16430   22/3/14  4    12      947      Work cluster     CBD area 2     41        23
4697    22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2   51        23
4911    22/3/14  3    12      1001     Shopping cluster Orchard Rd 3   61        45
11126   22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2   72        54
```

Comment: Could you had your expected output, ie. what newtbl looks like with the sample data you shared?

Comment: i've edited my question, pls look at it :) @scoa

Comment: in the second data frame, what do you want to compare "hour" from the first data frame to?

Comment: I want to compare with the attributes `foreigners` and `locals` by category. To calculate using the formula that i have derived. @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: `footfallHour <- (tbl1$hour/(newHourSum-previousHour)) * tbl2$Foreigners` what exactly is `Foreigners`? - and where does `hourSum` comes from? is it the sum of the column `hour`for all of the 635 rows?

Comment: Foreigners is the number of footfall count for foreigners. and yes, hourSum is the sum of the column `hour` for all 635 rows which i've found is 3588. @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: and "previousHour" is for eg. row 1 hour is 3. row 2 hour is 4. so the previousHour for row 2 is 3. get it? That's what i've been trying to output from. @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: and what is it that you're getting now?

Comment: nothing at the moment. can you please check if my codes is right on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226508/for-loop-equally-sized-data-frames-in-r) I've tried to sort it out @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: Check your other question, I answered there