# Storing every nth row in Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, row, element

Hi I'm not sure how to store every row as an element in Java from a csv file so that i can check with the previous element from the same column. Does anyone know how?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm working on a data frame which looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abw4v8h69e92yeq/idafootfall.csv?dl=0)

Here's how it looks like:

```
shape id day     hour week id footfall category          area name
22496   22/3/14  3    12      634      Work cluster     CBD area 1  
22670   22/3/14  3    12      220      Shopping cluster Orchard Road 1  
23287   22/3/14  3    12      723      Airport  Changi  Airport 2   
16430   22/3/14  4    12      947      Work cluster     CBD area 2  
4697    22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2    
4911    22/3/14  3    12      1001     Shopping cluster Orchard Rd 3    
11126   22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2
```

and so on... until 635 rows return.

I want to store every `hour` as element so i can compare it with my other dataset.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
package network;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class footfall {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // New BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "C:\\only18date.csv"));

    // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
        break;
        }
        list.add(line);
    }

    // Close it.
    reader.close();

    // Print size of ArrayList.
    System.out.println("Lines: " + list.size());

    // Print each line.
    int size = list.size();
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    String[] data=(list.get(i)).split(",");
    String n= data[3];
    System.out.println(n);
    }  // so i can check every row with the previous value from the column.    // &  in order for me to check the previous value i can simply write n-1 or //something like that but im not sure how to do it :/
// i want to store every nth row from column 3 as an element
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still dont understand what you means by "nth" row. Is it like you want to get the 3rd row, 4th row, 100th row from the entire data set (635 rows) ? Is the csv file change over time ? You say "as an element". Element of what ? List ? Set ? or array ?

Comment: Thanks for your concern! My apologies, what i meant by nth row is i want to get every row as an element from a column and store in a variable so that i can make use of it. @FerdinandNeman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it in that way:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class footfall {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // New BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\idafootfall.csv"));

        // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
        String line;
        while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            list.add(line);

        // Close it.
        reader.close();

        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\category.csv"));

        // Add all lines from file to ArrayList.
        Map<String,Category> map=new HashMap<String, Category>();
        String line2;
        while ((line2=reader2.readLine())!=null){
            String[] split=line2.split(",");
                try
                {
                  map.put(split[0], new                         Category(Double.valueOf(split[1]),Double.valueOf(split[2])));
               }
               catch(NumberFormatException e)
               {
               }

        }

        // Close it.
        reader2.close();

        // Print size of ArrayList.
        System.out.println("Lines: " + list.size());

        // Print each line.
        int size = list.size();
        int previousHour=0;
        List<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            try
            {
            String[] data = (list.get(i)).split(",");
            System.out.println(data[2]);


            double newHourSum = Integer.parseInt(data[2]) - previousHour;
            double footfallHour = ( Integer.parseInt(data[2])/(newHourSum-previousHour)) * map.get(data[0]).foreigners;

            previousHour=Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
            // i want to store every nth row from column 3 as an element
          } catch(NumberFormatException e){}
        }
    }
}

class Category{
    Double foreigners;
    Double locals;

    public Category(Double foreigners,Double locals){
        this.foreigners=foreigners;
        this.locals=locals;
    }
}
```

Now I have implemented the code like the version from the link.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But why do you intialize n=3? What I meant by nth row is I want each row of a column to be an element so I can use it after. :)

Comment: And the reason why I want to use it after because of checking every row purposes

Comment: Then I misunderstood your questions. I hope the edited version is what you are searching for.

Comment: How do i use elements if you add it in?

Comment: I wanted to do this: `for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
  String[] data=(list.get(i)).split(",");
  String n= data[3];
     System.out.println(n);
 } ` so i can check every row with the previous value from the column. &  in order for me to check the previous value i can simply write n-1 or something like that but im not sure how to do it :/

Comment: I want to keep check the previous value from the column and store it as a variable. Pls look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219451/for-loop-in-r-and-checking-previous-value-from-a-column) question if i confuse you more. I'm trying to do this in Java

Comment: You should save the previous values into the elements list and then you could check the previous element like that elements.get(elements.size()-2); You should use -2 because the index starts at 0 so that elements.size-1 is the current element and elements.size-2 is the previous element.

Comment: How do I save previous values into elements list in this case there's 600 values

Comment: If you need only the previous value then you could save them in a variable.

Comment: Yes is there a way how to do it? Coz that's what I've been trying to look for

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a life saver. Will try it :)

Comment: I have tried your codes and i received an error showing: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Foreigners"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at network.footfall.main(footfall.java:36)` do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87979/discussion-between-leonid-glanz-and-studentdoubts).

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to do that the quick & dirty way.

**Example** (note: it differs from your code a bit in order to be self-contained)

```
// emulating csv file
String[] lines = {
    "shape id day     hour week id footfall category          area name",
    "22496   22/3/14  3    12      634      Work cluster     CBD area 1",  
    "22670   22/3/14  3    12      220      Shopping cluster Orchard Road 1",  
    "23287   22/3/14  3    12      723      Airport  Changi  Airport 2",   
    "16430   22/3/14  4    12      947      Work cluster     CBD area 2",  
    "4697    22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2",    
    "4911    22/3/14  3    12      1001     Shopping cluster Orchard Rd 3",    
    "11126   22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2"  
};
List<Integer> hours = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//                           | begin of input
//                           || any number of characters, reluctantly quantified
//                           ||  | 1+ whitespace
//                           ||  |   | single digit in group 1 (the hours)
//                           ||  |   |   | 1+ whitespace
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.+?\\s+(\\d)\\s+");
// here you probably want to only add the m.group(1) to your list, possibly as integer as it's done here
for (String s: lines) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        hours.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
    }
}
System.out.println(hours);
```

**Output**

```
[3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```

**Note**

The example above would require your data to be consistent.

If your hours can be `> 9`, you may want to change the `(\\d)` part of the pattern with `(\\d{1,2})`.

Comment: thank you for your reply! but my csv file contains 312 lines and it would be very tedious for me to declare as String lines and i want the output to be in vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want, but see if this helps.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=n) { // Notice the i+=n to get every nth row.

        String[] data = (list.get(i)).split(",");
        System.out.println(data[3]);
        // i want to store every nth row from column 3 as an element
    }
```

Note: You can change the initial value of `i` to adjust the exact row you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! And what exactly do i initialize `n` as?