# for loop: not equally-sized data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, for-loop

I'm working on a data frame which looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abw4v8h69e92yeq/idafootfall.csv?dl=0)

Here's how it looks like:

```
shape id day     hour week id footfall category          area name
22496   22/3/14  3    12      634      Work cluster     CBD area 1  
22670   22/3/14  3    12      220      Shopping cluster Orchard Road 1  
23287   22/3/14  3    12      723      Airport  Changi  Airport 2   
16430   22/3/14  4    12      947      Work cluster     CBD area 2  
4697    22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2    
4911    22/3/14  3    12      1001     Shopping cluster Orchard Rd 3    
11126   22/3/14  3    12      220      Residential area Ang Mo Kio 2
```

and so on... until 635 rows return.

with the other dataset that I want to compare with can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6wf54t8xlpef2ds/footfall.csv?dl=0)

Here's how it looks like:

```
category         Foreigners Locals
Work cluster     1600000    3623900
Shopping cluster 1800000    3646666.667
Airport          15095152   8902705
Residential area 527700     280000
```

and also [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5aq79o0yei6ts11/previousHour.csv?dl=0) last dataset that i want to compare with their `previousHour`

The first and second share the same attribute, i.e. `category` & first and third dataset share the same attribute `hour`.

As for `previousHour` based on `category`. Eg, for `workcluster` [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cczqi9rf6bmipw/workcluster.csv?dl=0)

The `previousHour` should look like this:

```
 hour
0
3
4
4
4
5
```

until 144 rows return... for each category.

Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zc1chxcaaevwkve/shopping.csv?dl=0) for `shopping` category

`previousHour` eg. for `shopping` should look like this:

```
hour
0
3
3
4
4
5
```

until 144 rows return...

Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0y9neech24e953/airport.csv?dl=0) for `airport` category

Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9xjps1w8jsyvue/residential.csv?dl=0) for `residential` category

all 144 rows return...

`SumHour` dataset:

```
category                sumHour
1   Airport             2208
2   Residential area    1656
3   Shopping cluster    1656
4   Work cluster        1656
```

Here's, what I ideally want to find in R:

```
    #for n in 1: number of rows{

        # calculate sumHours(in SumHours dataset) - previousHour = newHourSum and store it as newHourSum
        # calculate hour/(newHourSum-previousHour) * Foreigners and store it as footfallHour
        # add to the empty dataframe }
```

I'm not sure how to do that and here's what i tried:

```
   mergetbl <- function(tbl1, tbl2)
{

  newtbl = data.frame(hour=numeric(),forgHour=numeric())

  ntbl1rows<-nrow(tbl1) # get the number of rows

  for(n in 1:ntbl1rows)
  {
    #for n in 1: number of rows{
    # check the previous hour from IDA dataset !!!!
    # calculate sumDate - previousHour = newHourSum and store it as newHourSum
    # calculate hour/(newHourSum-previousHour) * Foreigners and store it as footfallHour
    # add to the empty dataframe }
    newHourSum <- 3588 - tbl1
    footfallHour <- (tbl1$hour/(newHourSum-previousHour)) * tbl2$Foreigners
    newtbl <- rbind(newtbl, footfallHour)



  }
}
```

But nothing happened to **newtbl**...

Here's what **ideally** looks like for `newtbl`:

```
hour   forgHour
0       1337.79 (the function should calculate this)
3       ...
3       ...
3      ...
4      ...
3      ...
```

and so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of ["for" loop in R and checking previous value from a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219451/for-loop-in-r-and-checking-previous-value-from-a-column)

Comment: Not really I've asked for different stuff @Pascal

Comment: if both the data.frames are of identical size, then you don't need the for loop

Comment: The data frames are not identical size especially for the second dataset @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: nothing happened to newtbl because you didn't put anything in it

Comment: There is no reference to the previous post. Please add.

Comment: can you manipulate your data to "plug" the second table into the first one? ie for each row, write the corresponding foreigners and locals?

Comment: How do I add in? @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: I thought I did for the last sentence newtbl <-rbind(newtbl,footfallHour) @FAURILLOUAmandine

Comment: The columns you're specifying when initialising the df do not correspond to any variables in your function. The error comes from there

Comment: If you want to initialise the df, it's better to leave it empty first `newtbl = data.frame()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking in terms of vectors gives this :

Try this:

```
### this is to get your Foreigners/Locals to be at the same size as tbl1


Foreigners=ifelse(tbl1$category=="Work cluster",tbl2$Foreigners[1], ifelse (tbl1$category=="Shopping cluster", tbl2$Foreigners[2], ifelse(tbl1$category=="Airport", tbl2$Foreigners[3], tbl2$Foreigners[4])))
Locals=ifelse(tbl1$category=="Work cluster",tbl2$Locals[1], ifelse (tbl1$category=="Shopping cluster", tbl2$Locals[2], ifelse(tbl1$category=="Airport", tbl2$Locals[3], tbl2$Locals[4])))
```

And now, the function

```
resultHour = function(tbl1, tbl2, ForeOrLoca)
{
previousHour = rep (0, nrow(tbl1))
for (i in 2:nrow(tbl1))
{
 previousHour[i] = tbl1$hour[i-1]
}

### The conditional sum matching the category from tbl1
NewHourSum = ifelse(tbl1$category=="Work cluster",sum(with(tbl1, hour*I(category == "Work cluster"))), ifelse (tbl1$category=="Shopping cluster", sum(with(tbl1, hour*I(category == "Shopping cluster"))), ifelse(tbl1$category=="Airport", sum(with(tbl1, hour*I(category == "Airport"))), sum(with(tbl1, hour*I(category == "Residential area"))))))

##and finally, this

hour = as.vector(tbl1$hour)

footfallHour <- (hour/(newHourSum - previousHour)) * ForeOrLoca
newtbl <- cbind(hour, footfallHour)
return (newtbl)
}
```

this is the output I get :

```
> head(newtbl)
 hour footfallHour
[1,]    3    1337.7926
[2,]    3    1506.2762
[3,]    3   12631.9264
[4,]    4    1785.2162
[5,]    3     441.7132
[6,]    3    1506.2762
```

Using the function:

```
TheResultIWant = resultHour (tbl1,tbl2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Will try this later :)

Comment: Do i put all inside the mergetbl() function?

Comment: I've test out your codes but the `newtbl` gives me the output of the previousHour instead.

Comment: For the resultHour() function, what dataset do you use for tbl1 and tbl2?

Comment: Tbl1 is ur data and tbl2 is where you find foreigners and locals

Comment: the footfallHour for the output is for the foreigners or the locals?

Comment: I get the output same as yours but im not able to save it. Do you know how to save it?

Comment: Like any function returning a result. savedresult = resultHour(tbl1, tbl2)

Comment: It's for the foreigners.

Comment: If the answer is right for your problem, please accept it.

Comment: How do you know that when you time foreigners it's the number based on its category?

Comment: I've added the `sumHour` dataset as I just find out that the sum of Hours is different based on its `category`. Much apologies. Do you know how to do it if its based on the category? Same formulas follows.

Comment: I added the code line you want. It sums according to the level of category from tbl1 and the rows match the positions from tbl1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88352/discussion-between-faurillou-amandine-and-studentdoubts).

Comment: Much apologies, for the previous hour, I realized the previous hour for the 1st hour in Shopping cluster is 0 as there's no previous hour for the category shopping at first. How do I do previous hour based on category and then do the same formulas all over again?

Answer (score 0):

For your new question.

Provided you cut your data frame into several containing only one category, you can use this function:

```
new_function_hour_result = function (tbl1_categ, vec_categ, prevHour_Categ, sumHour_Categ)
hour = as.vector(tbl1_categ$hour)

footfallHour <- (hour/(sumHour_Categ- previousHour)) * vec_categ
newtbl <- cbind(hour, footfallHour)
return (newtbl)
}
```

With `tbl1_categ` your data frame for a given category, `vec_categ` your foreigner or local data for a given category, `prevHour_Categ` the previousHour for a given category, and finally `sumHour_Categ` the sumHour for a given category.

***To get your vectors to be the same size as the df they will be compared to :***

for instance, *for the `vec_categ`* in the case locals/airport category:

```
locals_airport = rep(category[3,3], nrow = nrow(tbl1_airport))
```

for foreigners and airport category: `foreig_airport = rep(category[3,2], nrow = nrow(tbl1_airport))`

this will repeat the value contained in `category[3,2]`, `nrow(tbl1_airport)` times.

for locals and workcluster: `locals_workcluster = rep(category[1,3], nrow = nrow(tbl1_workcluster))`

***and so on for each vector (ie `prevHour_Categ`, `sumHour_Categ`, `vec_categ`) for each category!!***

Comment: I cant put the statement `foreig_airport = rep(category[3,2], nrow = nrow(tbl1_airport))` inside the function? and where do i get `tbl1_airport` from?

Comment: As for the `locals_workcluster` statement, the tbl1_airport you meant tbl1_workcluster? But im not sure where do i get this tbl1_airport, tbl1_workcluster etc from?

Comment: Also, how do you know which `category[n,n]` for each statement?

Comment: I tried your codes, i have error while running it... Do i just run the function? Sorry for the all this confusion!

Comment: in the chat, you told me you divided your data frame into 4 smaller ones. I assumed that was so each data frame only had one category in it. I edited `locals_workcluster`, that was an error of copy/paste. as for your third question, it's because I looked at the data in `category` that I know which (row, column) is needed.

Comment: Yes I did, I edited my question and put the 4 dataset if you wanna know how it looks like. But when I run the function, it says that it has no equal size. I'm not sure which dataset to use for the last tbl: sumHour_Categ my sumHours is just 2 columns, 4 rows only shown in the qn

Comment: The previousHour also I've separated to only one category. The only problem is hour do I times with the locals and foreigners?

Comment: Yes, somehow... For the times vec_categ my data frame contains both foreigners and locals so do you meant times locals_foreigners instead?

Comment: `vec_categ` is supposed to be a vector, there shouldn't be any issue of dimensionnality here

Comment: Okay , thank you so much for your time.. Will try the code later :)